# How to assign user with civicrm membership to specific role?

Tags: 7, civicrm

I'm using D7 CiviCRM 4.4.6.

There are two roles in my site: authenticated user, member.

Those who registered in my site is authenticated user.
Only users who have active civicrm membership will assigned to both user and member role.

How can I configure the system so that when it run cron, those who have civicrm membership will be added "member" role?

Answer (score 2):

Can't think of any better way to say this than the docs: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviMember+Roles+Sync

makes it really simple and straightforward.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have resolved this issue is using CiviMember Roles Sync to tie a membership to a Drupal role.

You can also do similar if the member is an organisation, by creating a smart group out of those that have a certain relationship and then use a similar Civi Groups sync to match it up to a Drupal role.